# Blending materials on rounded surface

Tags: materials

i have a problem with blending materials. I made 3d text and i need to use curve modificator for it, but it must consists two materials one is for face and second is for sides and it must be blend gradually not sharp. And it is alright untill i used curve modificator. I have totally no idea how to bend the gradient for blending materials, how i can use the circle, what i made for modificator?
[image: what i need to fix]

[image: normal blending]

Comment: I will work on this. You might try the geometry node -> position, then find the distance from where the circle is. PS: it’s just modifier. Modificator isn’t a word.

Comment: Hello :). Best to use UV mapping, it stays the same if you bend the shape.

Comment: @JachymMichal True. If you never need to edit this text or change the font, go with UV mapping.

Comment: thx for fast answers!)) UV mapping is solution that terrifying me)))

Comment: 2 ZargulTheWizard but blender know the radius of curve that i've used for modificator, i can't believe it can't be applyed to colorramp node.

Comment: +1 for the modificator again :D Zargul will love you :D